# How to create a menu tree using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a menu tree using HTML. I had a search on Google, but they are providing some software to download in order to create this. But I need some script and HTML tags to do this.
Can anyone help me solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'menu tree'?

Comment: The tree which expands and displays all the submenus when clicked on the main menu

Comment: Ah, I should've got that, really...thanks =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is something very simple to start with.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/navigate1.htm

### **EDIT**

Implementing what I learned from @sushil bharwani. 
Here is how I found the above URL i.e. at the courtesy of @sushil bharwani
http://www.google.co.in/search?q=Menu+Tree+using+UL+L&qscrl=1

Answer (score 3):

You **don't** need to use JavaScript (unless you want compatibility with outdated browsers), you can achieve it with HTML+CSS alone. And in a much more semantically-correct way. :)

You can make [vertical dropdown menus](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/vertical.html) or (prettier example) [horizontal menus](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/) using the techniques explained in the [Sons of Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) article at HTMLDog.
Simple and meaningful.

---

## Sample

Here is a simple example. In it you can see the hover functionality working perfectly.

The CSS is not good, because it's only a sample.
To work on the style, disable the `display: none;` line: that will stop the submenus from hiding when not hovered, and you can work on styling everything.
When you are done, simply re-enable the `display: none;` line to get the submenus to hide and only show on hover.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
<p>Collapsing:</p>
<ul class="collapsable">
    <li>a<ul>
        <li>a1
        <li>a2
        </ul>
    <li>b<ul>
        <li>b1
        </ul>
</ul>
<p>Not collapsing:</p>
<ul>
    <li>a<ul>
        <li>a1
        <li>a2
        </ul>
    <li>b<ul>
        <li>b1
        </ul>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav li:hover {
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
nav li>ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav .collapsable li>ul {
    display: none;
}
nav li>ul::before {
    content: ": { ";
}
nav li>ul::after {
    content: " } ";
}
nav li:hover>ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav li>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav li>ul>li+li::before {
    content: ", ";
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8dxv/

Comment: It would be nice to indroduce parts of the exemples you link to, before they break.

Comment: *Nooo, it has been up for 8 years, and now you jinxed it!* Thanks for the suggestion, I added a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of javascript and a knowledge around CSS you can convert a simple UL LI list to a menu tree. its right that you can use jQuery if you understand it.

You can narrow your google search by Menu Tree using UL Li. or CSS to convert UL LI to tree.

Comment: Great! I appreciate the way you are also showing her how she could also find it herself.

Comment: Thanks .. i believe a self search lets u learn more around the area i know i was also searching this two yrs back.

Comment: ! I'm surprised that you have reached this reputation in 27 days. Its almost what I achieved in 10 months :D.
Its a big achievement for you. Congratulations!!!

Answer (score 0):

Navigation menus are mostly created using a combination of UL and LI.

```
<UL id="Menu">
    <LI>Home</LI>
    <LI>Links</LI>
</UL>
```

And you can insert UL inside LI element and thus get a tree structure for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simply way to do it if you don't want to write one yourself..

http://www.mycssmenu.com/#css-menu-demo

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into some of the online tools that builds the menu for you. E.g. [CSS Menu Generator](http://www.cssmenumaker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you will find your answer, but here is a list with several different types of vertical menus
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic2/index.htm
no javascript is involved in those examples